# Unknown date column class after using lubridate make_datetime in R

Tags: r, lubridate, posixct

I had 6 numeric columns of year, month, day, hour, min and sec, and combined them using `make_datetime` in the `lubridate` package, as such:

```r
data$date <- make_datetime(year = data$Year, month = data$Month, day = data$Day, hour = data$Hour, min = data$Min, sec = data$Sec)
```

However, the class of the new date column is `unknown`. When I investigated with `class(data$date)`, it returns `"POSIXct" "POSIXt"`. I tried fixing it with:

```r
class(data$date) <- "POSIXct"
```

When I hover over the header in the data table, the class remains unknown. But when I put `class(data$date)` in the command line, it returns `"POSIXct"`. I suspect that I have not resolved the issue because I cannot use other functions like `timeAverage (openair)`.

Does anyone know if this is normal for `make_datetime`, and if I can fix this? Thanks

**EDIT**

This is the `head(data)`

```
 Year Month Day Hour Min Sec                Date
1: 1979     1   1    0   0   0 1979-01-01 00:00:00
2: 1979     1   1    1   0   0 1979-01-01 01:00:00
3: 1979     1   1    2   0   0 1979-01-01 02:00:00
4: 1979     1   1    3   0   0 1979-01-01 03:00:00
5: 1979     1   1    4   0   0 1979-01-01 04:00:00
6: 1979     1   1    5   0   0 1979-01-01 05:00:00
```

Comment: This would be far easier to help troubleshoot with sample data, please see https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: @r2evans I've added the first six lines of data. Hope this helps.

Comment: (1) `POSIXct` timestamps need to be class `c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")`; R allows multiple class inheritance, it's important for many reasons. Don't shorten it to just one of those two. (2) I cannot reproduce your assertion of class `unknown`: every method I use to look at `data` in general and `data$date` specifically produce a known class.

Comment: I guess I should say I'm using emacs/ess, not RStudio ...

Comment: Thank you, it makes sense that there is nothing fundamentally wrong with my data. Now I'm just curious why I can't use ```timeAverage```, but I guess that is another question altogether...

Answer (score 0):

It is just the visual behaviour of RStudio, in the environment tab it shows the first class only for each column, in the View table hovering it shows unknown quite often for "not common" classes (not sure what the criteria are for that). So there is nothing lost or wrong with your data.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I initially asked this question because I've never used ```make_datetime``` before, and I wrongly thought that the column class was the reason why the ```timeAverage``` function didn't work for me. I will find other ways of debugging my code :)